# Ubuntu 12.04.2 server auto enter root shell in recovery mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wanted to leverage the "recovery mode", which allows me to enter root shell without creating any normal user accounts. It used be working on Ubuntu 10.04. Now for 12.04, it can still can be configured to recovery mode by change "GRUB_DEFAULT" in /etc/default/grub from "0" to "1". However, when it automatically enters "recovery", a second menu appears and I have to scroll down to choose "Drops to root shell" to get to prompt console. How to bypass that "Recovery menu" as I want to boot the system automatically into root shell?

Comment: After further study, I thought I had figured it out. There is known issue of GRUB in the 12.04 64bits, where the change of timeout is not converged into final grub.cfg (/etc/grub). You have to revise "set timout=-1" to "set timeout=0" in the auto generated grub.cfg or do below,

               §/etc/grub.d/00_header
               –In the make_timeout() function: replace the if/else/if block with "set timeout=${2}“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further study, I thought I had figured it out. Two changes are needed:

(1) update the grub.cfg to customize recovery mode
     - open /boot/grub/grub.cfg
     - revise the menuentry "linux ...... ro recovery nomodest ...... " to "linux ...... ro single ...... "
(2) There is known issue of GRUB in the 12.04 64bits, where the change of timeout is not converged into final grub.cfg (/etc/grub). You have to revise "set timout=-1" to "set timeout=0" in the auto generated grub.cfg or do below,

```
           §/etc/grub.d/00_header
           –In the make_timeout() function: replace the if/else/if block with "set timeout=${2}“
```

before executing update-grub.

Actually, you should do step (2) first and then step (1)